# Add intellisense in VS2017 for html attributes and element

Tags: html, angularjs-directive, visual-studio-2017, jsdoc, javascript-intellisense

I'm using VS2017 (with new Salsa Javascript Language service) for a project with angularJS, creating html components.
I have js-doc installed, which help me a lot with intellisense for js classes.
I want to add intellisense for my custom elements with custom attributes.
Exemple:
I create an element:
ax-dropdown-popup, with attributes: datasource, item-id-field, item-display-field,popup-relative-left, etc.

**What I need to do to have intellisense with theses attributes when I create an html element ax-dropdown-popup?**

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a solution for this problem, but I start learning Angular with Typescript using PhpStorm.
The Intellisense is amazing: not only in typescript files, but also for html custom element: I can see what custom attributes I have for current element tag:

[image]